# How to open DatePicker calendar pop-up window without mouse click?

Tags: javafx, datepicker

When I click on the calendar icon of JavaFx DatePicker it opens a pop-up calendar window to select a date.

But I want to open this calendar window using method calling. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DatePicker#show()` method.

```
datePicker.show();
```